# Me sale el error TypeError: inventario.eliminar_producto() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nombre' de este codigo

Tags: python, visual-studio, sintaxis, typeerror

El problema radica en que falta un argumento pero sinceramente no se que falta
El código debe permitir a los usuarios agregar, eliminar y actualizar
productos en un inventario de tienda.

```
class Producto:
    def __init__(self,nombre,precio,cantidad):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.precio=precio
        self.cantidad=cantidad
        
class ProductoPerecedero(Producto):
    def __init__(self, nombre, precio, cantidad,fecha_vencimiento):
        super().__init__(nombre, precio, cantidad)
        self.fecha_vencimiento=fecha_vencimiento
class ProductoNoPerecedero(Producto):
    def __init__(self, nombre, precio, cantidad,tipo_empaque):
        super().__init__(nombre, precio, cantidad)
        self.tipo_empaque=tipo_empaque
class inventario:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lista_productos=[]
        
    def agregar_producto(self,producto):
        self.lista_productos.append(producto)
    def eliminar_producto(self,nombre):
        for producto in self.lista_productos:
            if producto.nombre==nombre:
                self.lista_productos.remove(producto)
                print("El producto se elimino correctamente")
                return
            print("No se encontro el producto")
    def mostrar_inventario(self):
        for producto in self.lista_productos:
            print(f"Producto:{producto.nombre}-Precio:{producto.precio}-Cantidad:{producto.cantidad}")
class inventarioAgregar(inventario):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
class inventarioEliminar(inventario):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
class inventario_actualizar(inventarioAgregar,inventarioEliminar):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def actializar_producto(self,nombre,nuevo_precio,nueva_cantidad):
        for producto in self.lista_productos:
            if producto.nombre==nombre:
                nuevo_producto=Producto(producto.nombre,nuevo_precio,nueva_cantidad)
                super().eliminar_producto(nombre)
                super().agregar_producto(nuevo_producto)
                print("El producto se actualizo correctamente")
                return
            print("No se encontro el producto en el inventario")
```

Lo que me dice la terminal es que abajo justo en donde deje el comentario esta el problema.

```
inventario = inventarioAgregar()
producto1 = ProductoPerecedero("Leche", 2.50, 10, "15/04/2023")
producto2 = ProductoNoPerecedero("Cereal", 3.50, 20, "Caja")
inventario.agregar_producto(producto1)
inventario.agregar_producto(producto2)
inventario.mostrar_inventario()
inventario_eliminar=inventarioEliminar()
inventario_eliminar.eliminar_producto(producto1)*se supone que aquí es el problema* 
inventario.mostrar_inventario()
```

Si es posible diganme vagamente cual es el problema, si la sintaxis esta mal y si hay algo que mejorar pero solucionar esto me resulta frustrante en mi nivel actual, Gracias.

Comment: Sustituye `producto1` por `producto1.nombre` para pasar una cadena en vez de un objeto...

Answer (score 0):

El problema es donde intentas eliminar un producto del inventario:

```
inventario_eliminar.eliminar_producto(producto1)
```

Aquí, estás pasando un objeto producto como argumento a la función eliminar_producto, pero deberías pasar el nombre del producto que deseas eliminar. En otras palabras, deberías pasar el nombre del producto como una cadena de texto. Por ejemplo, para eliminar el producto "Leche", deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
inventario_eliminar.eliminar_producto("Leche")
```

De esta manera, el método eliminar_producto podra buscar y eliminar el producto correcto de la lista de productos. Espero que esto solucione tu problema.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

tenemos unos pequeños problemitas conceptuales.
Estás creando clases cuando deberías implementar funciones.
Tus palabras: "***El código debe permitir a los usuarios agregar, eliminar y actualizar productos en un inventario de tienda***".
Esto parece indicar que hay una tienda y un inventario, ya tenés la clase **`inventario`**, por lo que las clases **`inventarioAgregar`**, **`inventarioEliminar`** e **`inventario_actualizar`**, están de más.

```
class inventario:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.lista_productos = []
        
    def agregar_producto( self, producto ):
        self.lista_productos.append( producto )

    def eliminar_producto( self, nombre ):
        for producto in self.lista_productos:
            if producto.nombre == nombre:
                self.lista_productos.remove( producto )
                print( "El producto se elimino correctamente" )
                return
            print( "No se encontro el producto" )

    def mostrar_inventario( self ):
        for producto in self.lista_productos:
            print( f"Producto:{producto.nombre}-Precio:{producto.precio}-Cantidad:{producto.cantidad}" )

    def actializar_producto( self, nombre, nuevo_precio,nueva_cantidad ):
        for producto in self.lista_productos:
            if producto.nombre == nombre:
                nuevo_producto = Producto( producto.nombre, nuevo_precio, nueva_cantidad )
                super().eliminar_producto( nombre )
                super().agregar_producto( nuevo_producto )
                print( "El producto se actualizo correctamente" )
                return
            print( "No se encontró el producto en el inventario" )

inventario = inventarioAgregar()
producto1 = ProductoPerecedero("Leche", 2.50, 10, "15/04/2023")
producto2 = ProductoNoPerecedero( "Cereal", 3.50, 20, "Caja" )
inventario.agregar_producto( producto1 )
inventario.agregar_producto( producto2 )
inventario.mostrar_inventario()
inventario.eliminar_producto( "Leche" ) #*se supone que aquí es el problema* 
inventario.mostrar_inventario()
```

Fijate que no agregué nada, todo estaba ahí, solo quite las clases "fantasmas", **`inventario_eliminar = inventarioEliminar()`** y cambié
**`inventario_eliminar.eliminar_producto( producto1 )`** por **`inventario.eliminar_producto( producto1 )`**.
Pruébalo y dime si funcionó.

Nota de edición: cambié el parámetro de **eliminar** por el nombre del producto, aunque se puede crear otro método que reciba como parámetro el objeto producto y lo elimine.

Comment: Tambien gracias por tu ayuda :D

Comment: Un placer poder ayudarte!!..

Comment: Estaba tratando de aplicar lo que me enseñaron de herencias, supongo que esta es mejor forma

Comment: Es que en general tu código está  **muy bien!!!**.